# Using BibTeX bibliography file for a conference paper with predefined style

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'm writing a conference paper that has to be formatted using certain `.sty` file. For all other work, I'm maintaining one `bibliography.bib`, I'd like to use here as well. Is it possible?

In the template, such an example of bibliography item inclusion is given:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{exampleCiteKey}
  Smith, John,
  \emph{An example reference}.
  Publishing House, UK,
  2nd Edition,
  1998.
\end{thebibliography}
```

The style definition says:

```
%%%%%%%
% Bibliography
%
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section*{\refname
        \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}}%
      \list{\small\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}
        \@bibsetup}%
      \small\renewcommand\newblock{\hskip .11em \@plus.33em \@minus.07em}%
      \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.=\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}

%% setup 8/10 type
\def\@bibsetup{%\itemindent=0pt
  \itemsep=2pt \parsep=0pt \parskip 8pt
  \small}

\def\sameauthor{\leavevmode\vrule height 2pt depth -1.6pt width 23pt}
```

What I normally do in my documents is:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain} %Style of Bibliography: plain / apalike / amsalpha...
\bibliography{bibliography} %You need a file 'bibliography.bib' for this.
```

When I tried merging the above two:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibliography{bibliography}
\end{thebibliography}
```

I'm getting an error saying `\bibliographystyle` is missing (adding it causes the bibliography to look different than required by conference organizers). Isn't there a way to use `bibliography.bib` and make it look as defined in `.sty`?

Comment: this conference expects you to type out all your references, rather than extract them from your database using bibtex: how many do you have?  if it's fewer than 10 (or so), it will probably be best to go with their (uneducated) method -- just write out your biblio.  if it's a large number of references, it may be possible to find a plausible replacement.  http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/showbst.html used to be a standard place to look, but they've mangled it and it's now only just readable; the other possibility is http://web.reed.edu/cis/help/LaTeX/bibtexstyles.html: looks neat.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I also think extracting the references I need is probably the easiest solution, and therefore optimal, at least for now. I was just wondering, if there was a way to make my bibliography look as they expected without the copy-paste work (which would probably be optimal assuming I'll face similar questions in the future). I'm guessing, there is not?

Comment: @wasteofspace Please turn your comment into an answer, so that this question is removed from the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the links wasteofspace. I also think extracting the references I need is probably the easiest solution, and therefore optimal, at least for now.